# what is the equivalent in windows to the SUDO command to move a phar file

Tags: windows, sudo

I understand that sudo is not availble in windows

i want to move a phar file from a directory to

```
sudo mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
```

i am following instructions from this site;
[installing word press for command line](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/wordpress-command-line-everything-you-need-to-know)

so, i am unclear whether i can just manually do it or need to use the sudo command.

I feel that it might be best to use the sudo commands/or equivalent window commands

Answer (score 1):

There is no sudo command in Windows but you can start a Command as administrator (right click on it) or if you want a command line you can look at `runas`

```
runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator cmd
```

Comment: what is the noprofile  and does the cmd move the file?

Comment: runas.exe cannot elevate to the unrestricted token if the administrator is UAC restricted, as is the case by default for all admins except for the legacy Administrator account (RID 500). The latter account is disabled by default due to this policy.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need sudo in Windows. If you need administrative permissions for some actions, you can start the commandline as administrator.

Comment: The ask is for the equivalent command prompt command, to temporarily enable admin privileges without opening an admin only instance.